# How to export entire Adobe Flex project?

Tags: php, sql, apache-flex, export, wamp

I currently have a flex project that uses the PHP data service and is connected to my local wamp server, but when I export it currently, I can't see any of the data on the device. How can I export everything or make the wamp server work remotely so that I can view the sql data on the device instead of just the computer I built it on?

Comment: In my opinion you can not connect to the local server remotely. You have to upload your PHP on a remote server and then to point your application to the end point of the remote server. For example: www.myremoteserver.com/services/gateway.php

Comment: Or I come up with another suggestion. You can install a webserver on the Android(if you are using Android). The you will point to your local web server on the phone. Check this link for Android: http://blog.laptopmag.com/android-web-server

Comment: Yes, I agree. After conducting much research, this is the only way it can be done. Thanks :)